# How to remove bubble from group one at a time CMU Cs Academy

Tags: python

My instructions is to move each bubble by 4 units until I pop it with my spikes in CMU Cs Academy. Then it should be removed from the group "bubbles".
When the spike touches the bubble then every bubble that is above it is removed from the group. Here's my current code:

```
app.background = gradient('midnightBlue', 'steelBlue', start='top')

# This draws the grass.
Oval(370, 440, 800, 200, fill='mediumSeaGreen')
Oval(130, 450, 800, 200, fill='forestGreen')

bubbles = Group()

spikes = Star(200, 300, 25, 3, fill='silver', roundness=20)

def onMousePress(mouseX, mouseY):
    bubbles.add(
        Circle(mouseX, 0, 25, border='white', opacity=50, fill=gradient('white', 'lightBlue', start='top-right'))
        )


def onMouseMove(mouseX, mouseY):
    spikes.centerX = mouseX

def onStep():
    # Move each bubble down by 4. If the bubble touches the spikes, it should be
    # remove from the group.
    ### (HINT: You'll need to use a shape method here!)
    ### Place Your Code Here ###
    for bubble in bubbles:
        bubble.centerY = bubble.centerY + 4
    if  spikes.hitsShape(bubbles):
        bubbles.remove(bubble)
```

I thought it will pop bubbles one by one but it didn't.

Comment: the question needs sufficient code for a minimal reproducible example:
https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example